# Edexcel Core Pure Maths Book 1/AS quartic equation question

Tags: factoring, quartics

[image]

From the book in the title, this is page 61, Ex.4C, Q9. I found all the other questions in the exercise (4C) relatively straightforward, but this one stumped me. I suppose you could guess a few values of alpha and r, but I'm not sure in an exam I would think I would be expected to "guess" 1/2 or -1/2 as a root.

I've tried a bunch of stuff and have shown my attempts below, but you can see that towards the bottom of my page of working I end up going round in circles and I'm not making any progress towards the answer.
Obviously I'm looking to use the methods they have given in the book to answer the questions, which are the equations immediately below.

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you divide by $3$ you get $1024 x^4 - 960 x^3 + 280 x^2 - 30 x + 1=0$ so any rational root would have to have the form $\pm \frac 1{2^n}$ for fairly small $n$.  I'd just search those before doing anything else.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something. How did you arrive at, "so any rational root would have to have the form +-1/2^n" ? Looks like you plucked this out of thin air.

Comment: That's the Rational Root Theorem.

Comment: But this equation is not guaranteed (nothing in the text of the problem says so) to have rational roots. It may have rational roots, or it may not.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the rational root theorem. And I'm not sure it's taught as a prerequisite to AS Further maths

Comment: Agreed, but it means that those are obvious first places to check before having to go all Ferrari on it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

Comment: The [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) is absolutely essential in the algebraic theory of polynomials.  True, nothing guarantees that the polynomial has any rational roots at all, but testing for rational roots is extremely fast and easy so why not start there?

Comment: OK after reading up on it, I can see how the rational root theorem is useful here. I wonder how you would answer a similar question where applying the rational root theorem didn't find you any rational roots. Could you use methods similar to Michael Rozenberg's answer, or somehow use the equations they have given in my question? I'm not sure, but I think this further question is well beyond the scope of this chapter (Chapter 4), so I'll learn the RRT now and park this question for another time.

Comment: I think I still stand by my statement that "The rational root theorem is not taught as a prerequisite to AS Further maths", so while all these comments and answers are helpful for me to answer the question and increases my knowledge, it might be a *bad question* for the level that it is presented i.e. AS Further Maths. How can other AS Level students be expected to know/ use the Rational Root Theorem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dave L. Renfro pointed out in a comment, note that, from the $ \sum \alpha\beta$ formulae, we have:

$\frac{35}{128} = \alpha^{2}(r+r^{2}+2r^{3}+r^{4}+r^{5})= \alpha^{2}r^{3}(\frac{1}{r^{2}}+\frac{1}{r}+2+r+r^{2})=\frac{1}{32}(S^{2}+S)$ where $S = \frac{1}{r}+r$.

Solve for $S$ to get a quadratic in $r$, then solve for $r$ etc.

Answer (score 1):

We need to solve $$1024x^4-960x^3+280x^2-30x+1=0.$$

Now, for all real $k$ we obtain:

$$1024x^4-960x^3+280x^2-30x+1=$$
$$=(32x^2-15x+k)^2-((64k-55)x^2-30(k-1)x+k^2-1),$$
which for $k=1$ gives:
$$1024x^4-960x^3+280x^2-30x+1=$$
$$=(32x^2-15x+1)^2-9x^2=(32x^2-18x+1)(32x^2-12x+1).$$
Can you end it now?

In the first step I used the following formula:
$$(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2ac+2bc.$$
Since $$(32x^4-15x+k)^2=1024x^4+225x^2+k^2-960x^3+64kx^2-30x,$$
we obtain:
$$1024x^4-960x^3+280x^2-30x+1=$$
$$=1024x^4+225x^2+k^2-960x^3+64kx^2-30x-64kx^2+55x^2+30kx-30x-k^2+1=$$
$$=(32x^2-15x+k)^2-((64k-55)x^2-30(k-1)x+k^2-1).$$

Comment: You're probably correct, but that method is beyond my current capability and certainly beyond AS Level maths, which is what this question is geared towards. In the question I did specifically say to use the equations given in the chapter. That said, I won't downvote this answer and would discourage deleting it because I/others might revisit it later and find it interesting/useful in some other context.

Comment: @Adam Rubinson I am ready to explain any step. What is your question?

Comment: How did you factorise/complete the square in the first line like that? Like how would you spot to do that

Comment: @Adam Rubinson I added something. See now.

Comment: Ok this seems like a sound method. How did you spot to use it? Or does it always work?

Comment: @Adam Rubinson It always works. Just sometimes we need to solve a cubic equation for to find a value of $k$.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thought as Lulu: if you factor out the 3, you get $$1024x^4-960x^3+280x^2-30x+1=0$$  So $\alpha(r\alpha)(r^2\alpha)(r^3\alpha)=r^6\alpha^4=\frac{1}{1024}$ (from your problem hints) or $r^3\alpha^2=\frac{1}{32}$ and $r=\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$ is a really quick first guess.

Comment: Ok, so you're saying you would be expected at this level to make a guess of 1/2. Maybe you're right, but up until this point the book makes it seem like you would only be expected to guess low integers as roots...

Comment: I'd advise you to get comfortable with the Rational Root Theorem, because it makes guessing far more effective.  In this case, the leading coefficient is a huge power of 2 and the constant term is 1, so that would lead people like me and Lulu to guess 1/2.  If it was a more normal problem with a leading coefficient of 1 and a large constant term, then we'd look for small factors of that constant term.

Comment: It's not about *me* being comfortable with the Rational Root Theorem, because it's not just about whether or not *I* can answer the question. It's about whether the question is suitable for the chapter it's presented in which is AS Level maths, and using the methods in the chapter to solve the question. The rest of the questions in the chapter use deductive reasoning and simultaneous equations to solve the problems. This question seems an odd on out in that regard. I have found quite a few of these dodgy questions in A & AS Level maths books. I suppose your guessing method will have to do.

Comment: @Adam Rubinson: **Possible non-guessing approach** --- The roots are in a geometric progression. Instead of the form provided, use $\beta R^{-3},$ $\beta R^{-1},$ $\beta R,$ and $\beta R^{3}.$ Then use the product of roots formula (the $R$'s cancel) and the sum-of-pairwise-products formula, in which $R^{-4} + R^{-2} + 2 + R^2 + R^4$ shows up as a factor, which gives rise to a reciprocal equation, so let $S = R^{-2} + R^{2},$ which leads to $S^2 + S$ showing up as a factor. Solve the $S$-quadratic equation, and then use the solution(s) to solve the corresponding $R$-quadratic equations.

Comment: Excellent answer Dave L. Renfro, although you don't have to change the form provided into beta and R, you can do the same trick directly. From the sum-of-pairwise-products formula, you can write $\frac{35}{128} = \alpha^{2}(r+r^{2}+2r^{3}+r^{4}+r^{5}) = \alpha^{2}r^{3}(\frac{1}{r^{2}}+\frac{1}{r}+2+r+r^{2}) = \frac{1}{32}(S^{2} + S)$ where $S = \frac{1}{r} + r$. Then we solve for S then from S we find r. If you're not sure where the $\alpha^{2}r^{3} = \frac{1}{32}$ comes from, it's in my original attempt to answer the question.

Comment: If you want to write this as an answer I'll accept it as it fits the criteria of the question.